# How to add state variable for a state changing but not updating output

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my project I have:

```
function App()

return <section>
    {!user ?  <SignIn /> : (chatroomName !== null ? <ChatRoom /> : <ChatRoomName />)}
 </section>
```

where I update chatroomName variable to be the name of an input in another function (ChatRoomName). Except when I change chatroomName in function ChatRoomName() it's not updating the ternary operator in function App(). How do I get it to change the ternary operator output when chatroomName is changed?

How do I get it to change the ternary operator output when chatroomName is changed?

Comment: Because chatroomName is a local state in ChatRoomName, so you can't use  chatroomName at App. You need to change chatroomName to global state, ex: reducer, redux
https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer

Answer (score 0):

A component will rerender if its state is updated. I'm assuming you have 2 `chatRoomName` state, one in the `App`, and one inside `ChatRoomName` component. When you update the state inside `ChatRoomname`, App won't be rerendered. What you need to do is to update the `App` state instead. To do that, you need to pass down the update state function to `ChatRoomName`, for example:

```
function App() {
    const [chatRoomName, setChatRoomName] = useState(null);
    return <section>
        {!user ?  <SignIn /> : (chatroomName !== null ? <ChatRoom /> : <ChatRoomName onUpdate={name => setChatRoomName(name)} name={chatRoomName} />)}
    </section>
}
```

Remove the name stat from `ChatRoomName` and when you click the update button, call `props.onUpdate(newName)`.

Comment: Yes this is amazing, thank you. I actually figured it out like half an hour before you posted and this was my exact solution. Looks like I need to study state variables and useStates more!